# How do I fix this XSS warning on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, xss

Code climate is warning us about a potential cross site scripting issue.  Is escapeHTML not sufficient here?

```
link_to(t(".button_text"), main_app.some_path(:id => (h(params[:id]))), :class => "btn")
```

Comment: you might want to just convert to an integer instead? `:id => params[:id].to_i`

Comment: id is not an integer unfortunately its a guid of some sort

Comment: What version of rails are you using? A few years back there was a unicode escaping vulnerability in the rails html_escape method. Never used Code Climate, but could be picking that up? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-security/Vr_7WSOrEZU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using an object fetched from the controller and passing it to the path helper?

```
def index
  @some_object = SomeObject.find(params[:id])
  [...]
end
```

and then in your view use this object to build the route ?

```
link_to(t(".button_text"), main_app.some_path(@some_object), :class => "btn")
```

Comment: This seems like a really strange way to go about it.  Create a whole object and a find method for the purposes of putting something that was on the querystring into a link for the next page.